# Differential Diophantine Equations?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, diophantine-equations, functional-equations

So this is both a question on its own as well as a request for where I can find information on a given topic.

Consider Differential Equations in two variables of the form:

$$P(Z,Z', Z'' ... Z^{[n]}, Y, Y', Y'' ... Y^{[m]}) = 0 $$

Where $P$ is a polynomial of its arguments all of whose coefficients are polynomial functions in a variable x, and $Z$ and $Y$ are polynomials in x as well (the ones we are looking to solve for).

An example

$$y' - z'' = 0$$

Asks for the set of polynomials $y$ and $z$ such that $y = z'$

More involved cases include:

$$y'' + y' = 2z'' + xz' + x^2 z'$$

Which as far as I know doesn't appear to have any trivial solutions.

This is basically the notion of diophantine equations but generalized to functions. How should I go about solving this and what area of mathematics would this correspond to?

Comment: This is not correct. To combine discrete values and infinitely small. Usually act differently. Solve a differential equation and only then decide Diophantine equation. For example, searching for his roots when they whole. If any integer coefficients.

Comment: You can search under *Differential Algebra*, though not if you are interested only in *polynomial* solutions.

Comment: That is correct I only want to consider polynomial solutions, @Individ I don't understand what exactly you meant